# How can you modify the file size property or read more bytes than it indicates?

Tags: macos, filesystems, file-management

A friend of mine saved a file when her computer (a Mac) crashed. She assumed the file was saved and didn't worry about it too much, but now she saw the file size is 0 bytes and the file is empty for obvious reasons.

It happened over a week ago and she performed many large file operations so far, so I told her she will most likely not be able to restore it, and in fact she had already coped with that anyways, even before I told her.

Nevertheless this got me wondering whether there are any admin tools (Windows, Mac or UNIX) to modify the file size properties, so the file system believes the file is larger, or if there is a possibility to read a number of bytes from the disk starting at the file's pointer, disregarding its size according to the file system table?

Because since the file was already saved before and was a plain text file (XML precisely), I figured by faking a larger file size the adjacent bytes from the disc would've been interpreted as if they belonged to the corrupted file. When you then open the file in a simple text editor, at least a part of the file could've been readable again unless the "free" clusters were already claimed by any other file or the file was partitioned right there. 
(N. B.: If it was possible, we would've then copied the file to a USB drive and then reduce the size again to resolve a possible duplicate allocation of that disk space.)

As written above, she has already coped with re-doing the work, but I wonder whether you can actually manipulate the file size property or read a fixed number of bytes disregarding the "valid data length" information by any means.

I tried to Google it, but Google does not seem to understand what I want to do. The only thing I found was `fsutil file setvaliddata <file> <length>` for Windows, but that doesn't seem to work. I tried to modify the size of a text file in an elevated shell, but apparently any other value for `length` than 200 results in "Error: wrong parameter" when 200 is the size in bytes my original file already had.

I also thought I had better chances for OSX since it is UNIX alike, but actually I haven't found anything else for any OS at all.